# Seasonal Decompose Interpretation

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, time-series, timeserieschart

**Q1) How to interpret the Seasonal Decompose plotted against the same dataset?**

**Q2) And, on the basis of Observed data-points, which makes more sense, and why?**

[image]

**Observations from Multiplicative Decomposition**:

- Seasonal & Trend chart scales between 0.99 to 1.00

**Observations from Additive Decomposition**:

- Seasonal chart scales between -3 to 3
- Trend chart scales between -2 to 2

**Code Used**:

```py
import statsmodels.datasets.co2 as co2
co2_df = co2.load().data
co2_data = co2_data.fillna(co2_data.interpolate()); co2_data.columns=["co2_interpolated"]

y = co2_data["co2_interpolated"]

decomposition_mul = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(y, model='multiplicative')
decomposition_add = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(y, model='additive')
```

Plot:

```py
def plotseasonal(res, axes, title):
    axes[0].title.set_text(title)
    res.observed.plot(ax=axes[0], legend=False)
    axes[0].set_ylabel('Observed')
    
    res.trend.plot(ax=axes[1], legend=False)
    axes[1].set_ylabel('Trend')
    
    res.seasonal.plot(ax=axes[2], legend=False)
    axes[2].set_ylabel('Seasonal')
    
    res.resid.plot(ax=axes[3], legend=False)
    axes[3].set_ylabel('Residual')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=4, sharex=False, figsize=(30,15))
plotseasonal(decomposition_mul, axes[:,0], title="Multiplicative")
plotseasonal(decomposition_add, axes[:,1], title="Additive")
```

Comment: This question might be better for the datascience or statistics stack exchange

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right, that make more sense. Thanks